# Finding eigenspaces of a matrix with parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following matrix:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3&0&0\\
k+2&1&0\\
5&k-1&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The exercise asks to find the eigenvalues of the matrix and, for all $k\in\mathbb{R}$, determine a basis of each eigenspace of the matrix.

Since ths is a lower triangular matrix, the eigenvalues are the values on the diagonals: $\lambda=3$ and $\lambda=1$.

Now, for $\lambda=3$ I need to find the null space of this matrix:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
k+2&-2&0\\
5&k-1&-2
\end{pmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
5&k-1&-2\\
k+2&-2&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

By reducing in row echelon form ($R_2\leftarrow5R_2-kR_1$ and then $R_2\leftarrow R_2-2R_1$):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
5&k-1&-2\\
0&-k^2-k-8&2k+4\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I'm stuck here because $-k^2-k-8$ doesn't have real roots. Any hints?

Comment: You have not reduced your matrices properly - how do you get rid of the $k$ in $a_{21}$ by taking away $a_{11}$?

Comment: Consider $k=-2,$ it is straightforward to finish. If $k\neq -2,$ the reducing operation has to be $R_2\leftarrow5R_2-(k+2)R_1.$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the $(1,3)$ entry of the last matrix should be $2k+4$, not $6$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I'm never changing the first row If I'm not mistaken

Comment: Quite right. I meant $(2,3)$.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you! Not sure if I should edit.

Comment: Probably.  In any case, make sure you apply the same fix to José Carlos's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $-k^2-k-8$ can’t be zero, you can safely divide by it and continue merrily on your way with the row-reduction. However, because you’re working in $\mathbb R^3$ there’s a much simpler way to find a basis for this null space. The row space of $A-3I$ is clearly spanned by its two nonzero rows, and the null space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its row space, so the null space of $A-3I$ is spanned by $$(k+2,-2,0)\times(5,k-1,-2) = (4,2k+4,k^2+k+8).$$

Comment: I understand you need to take the transpose of the columns of $Row(A)$ to find $Nul(A)$, however I don't know why you multiply the two vectors together with ×.

Comment: @Cesare We’re looking for any nonzero vector that’s orthogonal to the two basis vectors of the row space—the nonzero rows of $A-3I$. The cross product of two vectors is orthogonal to both of those vectors, so...

Comment: @Cesare As far as transposing goes, I left off the superscript $T$’s to avoid clutter. It makes no difference to the actual computation.

Answer (score 2):

Since $-k^2-k-8$ has no real roots, you can divide the second line by it (for every $k\in\mathbb R$); you will get$$\begin{bmatrix}5&k-1&-2\\0&1&-\frac{2k+4}{k^2+k+8}\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$And now you can use that $1$ from the middle of the matrix to eliminate the $k-1$ from the first row.

Comment: How would you then go about finding the basis of the eigenspace? After eliminating the $k-1$ from the first row there's still a lot going on in the system $\begin{pmatrix}5&k&-2+a\\0&1&a\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ with $a=-\frac{2k+4}{k^2+k+8}$.

Comment: After adding to the first row of my matrix the second row time $1-k$, you get$$\begin{bmatrix}5&0&-\frac{20}{k^2+k+8}\\0&1&-\frac{2k+4}{k^2+k+8}\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$So, you get the $1$-dimensional space$$\left\{(x,y,z)\,\middle|\,x=\frac4{k^2+x+8}z\wedge y=\frac{2k+4}{k^2+k+8}z\right\}.$$